# Only last element of dictionary is adding into Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary and I am trying to load all of its data into Core Data.
However, it is inserting only the last element into Core Data.

```
NSArray *NameArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"Sections"];
for (NSDictionary *Dictionary in NameArray) {

    [section setValue:[Dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] forKey:@"name"];

}
```

Comment: what should i do to populate all object in to coreData ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the value for "name" key in every iteration. Thats why only last one gets saved. You should insert a new object or update existing one for every dictionary item.

```
NSArray *NameArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"Sections"];
for (NSDictionary *Dictionary in NameArray) {
    Section *newSection = <#create new object or fetch existing one#>
    [newSection setValue:[Dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] forKey:@"name"];
}
```